# Медленно отрабатывает Delphi программа на Android

Tags: android, delphi

Как известно, Delphi XE5 стал поддерживать разработку под Android. Так вот, моя первая программа, этот вывод цикла от 0 до 17 в Мемо, в итоге у меня это заняло 4 секунды зависания программы..

Отладку делал сразу в телефоне, телефон Xiaomi mi2s, CPU Snapdragon 600 4x1.7GHz, то есть не в телефоне дело. С чего такое зависание программы?
И вот такой вопрос, как компилируется программа, при компиляции код Delphi заменяется на эквивалентный ему Java-код ? или там и Java-код и Delphi-код, тогда это бы объясняло заторможенность программы...

И это, реализованы ли все возможности Android API которые можно сделать в Java, сделать их в Delphi ? или там ограниченный функционал?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задержка связана в связи с синхронизацией с реально работающим устройством, потому так медленно. Привыкайте))
Вместо телефона подключите эмулятор, повторите. Может быстрее будет.

Покопайтесь в настройках, документации мб можно как-то ускорить.

Нет, Delphi код НЕ превращается в Java и прочее, а компилируется в бинарную SOшку(аналог DLL под Linux).

Думаю, все, что реализуется подключаемым SDK - может использоваться и в Delphi.

Не тупите, а переходите к практике с интересующими вопросами. Попробовать лучше, чем ждать у моря погоды с ответами на форумах/чатах и .т.д. и т.п

Comment: Цикл от 1 до 100 примерно 30-40 сек заполняло. Надеюсь это из-за отладки, релизная, имею надежду, будет лучше)

Comment: не писал на делфях, но возник вопрос там что компилить под каждый проц придётся?

Comment: Реалия естественно будут лучше, даже игры можно писать FireMonkey же.

Comment: Релиз я так понимаю делать через: Projects->Options->DelphiCompiler и там выбрать target:Android release взамен debug ?

Comment: @ProkletyiPirat, зачем? Есть же версии SDK которые поддержвиет компилятор. Сибираете 2.2 андроид - летает на всех процах. Собираете 4.0 - не летает на тех что не тянут >2.3.

@Юра Сучко, скорее всего) В это я сам сильно пока не вникал.Так, балуюсь.